# Yup validation -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') at eval (changePassword.vue?18d1:231:1)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yup

I'm trying to do a change password interface. where the old password, the new password and the retyped new password are required and the new password and retyped new password should be the same.

This is my Yup schema:

```
const changePasswordSchema = yup.object().shape({
    passwordValueOld: yup.string().required('Debe ingresar su contraseña actual'),
    newPasswordValue: yup.string().required('Debe ingresar la nueva contraseña'),
    retypePassword: yup
    .string()
    .oneOf([yup.ref('newPasswordValue'), null], 'Las nuevas contraseñas no coinciden')
    .required('Debe confirmar la nueva contraseña'),
});
```

I have the following data:

```
data() {
    return {
        usernameValue: 'Usuario',
        rutValue: 'xxxxxxx-x',
        nombreValue: 'Nombre',
       passwordFieldTypeOld: 'password',
       passwordFieldTypeNew: 'password',
       passwordFieldTypeRetype: 'password',
       success: false,
        values: {
            passwordValueOld: '',
            newPasswordValue: '',
            retypePassword: '',
        },
        errors: {
             passwordValueOld: '',
             newPasswordValue: '',
             retypePassword: '',
        },
    };
},
```

The validate function is the following:

```
validate(field) {
    changePasswordSchema
    .validateAt(field, this.values)
    .then(() => {
        this.errors[field] = '';
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        this.errors[err.path] = err.message;
    });
},
```

and the function where I validate the input is the following:

```
async changePassword() {
    changePasswordSchema
    .validate(this.values, { abortEarly: false })
    .then(async () => {
        const check = await checkPassword(this.usernameValue, this.values.passwordValueOld);
        if ((await check.status) !== 200) {
            throw 'La contraseña actual, no es correcta';
        } else this.success = true;
        // Solicitud para cambiar contraseña
        // const answer = await changePassword(this.usernameValue, this.rutValue, this.nombreValue, this.newPasswordValue);
        // if ((await answer.status) === 200) {
        // // SUCCESS
        // }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    err.inner.forEach((error) => {
        this.errors = { ...this.errors, [error.path]: error.message };
    });
});
```

The idea is after validation, check if the old password is the same as in the DB, but when all inputs are correct, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at _callee$ (changePassword.vue?18d1:218:1)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63:1)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294:1)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25:1)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21:1)

changePassword.vue?18d1:231 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of
undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at eval (changePassword.vue?18d1:231:1)
```

At this point I know its the validate function in changePassword going to the catch... but I have no idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end. The problem wasn't the code from the .vue file but rather, the exporting of the checkPassword function from another file.

I wrote the helper function as:

```js
async function checkPassword(username, password){
 /*CODE*/
}

export default { checkPassword }
```

And what solved it was putting and export before the function itself, as follows:

```
export async function checkPassword(username, password){
 /*CODE*/
}

export default { checkPassword }
```